# Conditional probability - n trials, each outcome occurs at least once.

Tags: probability

> Problem: Consider $n$ independent trials in which each trial results in one
>   of the outcomes $1,\dots,k$ with respective probabilities $p_1,\dots , p_k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i= 1$. Suppose further that $n > k$, and that we are interested in determining the probability that each outcome occurs at least once.

To begin, note that if we start by conditioning on $N_k$ (the number of times
that outcome $k$ occurs) then when $N_k > 0$ the resulting conditional probability will equal the probability that all of the outcomes $1, \dots, k−1$ occur at least once when $n−N_k$ trials are performed, and each results in outcome $i$ with probability $p_i/\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}, i = 1,\dots , k − 1$. We could then use a similar conditioning step on these terms. To follow through on the preceding idea, let $A_{m,r}$, for $m \le n, r \le k$, denote the
event that each of the outcomes $1, \dots, r$ occurs at least once when $m$ independent trials are performed, where each trial results in one of the outcomes $1,\dots , r$ with respective probabilities $p_1/P_r, \dots, p_r/P_r$, where $P_{r}=\sum_{j=1}^r p_r$. Let $P(m, r) = P(A_{m,r})$ and note that $P(n, k)$ is the desired probability. To obtain an expression for $P(m, r)$, condition on the number of times that outcome $r$ occurs. This gives

\begin{align}P(m,r)&=\sum_{j=0}^mP(A_{m,r}\mid r \text{ occurs j times}) \binom{m}{j}\left(\frac{p_r}{P_r}\right)\left(1-\frac{p_r}{P_r}\right)\\[0.2cm]&=\sum_{j=1}^{m-r+1}P(m-j, r-1)\binom{m}{j}\left(\frac{p_r}{P_r}\right)\left(1-\frac{p_r}{P_r}\right)\end{align}

I understand first expression, but I couldn't understand second. Why $m-r+1$ and not $m-j+1$? $m$ is trials, $r$ is outcomes. How can two variables use together? Please explain second expression step by step. Thanks in advance!